# Google Firebase: handling user sign on for first time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am using Realtime Database to store user meals and meal ingredients for this meal planner app I am making. When the users open the app, the app uses their uid to get their data from the database so they can generate a meal plan with meals they have added previously. However, I am not sure how to handle the case in which a user is launching the app for the first time. In this scenario, I want the app to add a new user to the database with the user's uid, and I want to handle adding a meal for a user who is launching the app for the first time. I have added comments for the places where I need new code to go. Can someone tell me how to do this, and maybe provide the code I need to implement this?

```
    private let database = Database.database().reference()
    private let auth = Auth.auth()
    
    var meals: [String] = []
    var mealIngredients: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let user = auth.currentUser {
            let userId = user.uid
            
            database.child("users").child(userId).child("meals").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                snapshot in
                guard snapshot.value is [String] else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.meals = snapshot.value as! [String]
            })
            
            database.child("users").child(userId).child("mealIngredients").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                snapshot in
                guard snapshot.value is [String] else {
                    return
                }
                
                self.mealIngredients = snapshot.value as! [String]
            })
        }
        
        else {
            /*User launching app for first time*/
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addMeal(_ sender: Any) {
        if let mealName = mealNameField.text, let mealIngredients = mealIngredientsField.text {
            if mealName != "" && mealIngredients != "" {
                self.meals.append(mealName)
                self.mealIngredients.append(mealIngredients)
                mealNameField.text = ""
                mealIngredientsField.text = ""
                
                guard let currentUser = auth.currentUser else {
                    return
                }
                
                let userId = currentUser.uid
                let userRef = database.child("users").child(userId)
                
                userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
                    if snapshot.exists() {
                        userRef.setValue(self.meals)
                        userRef.setValue(self.mealIngredients)
                    }
                    
                    else {
                        /*Adding new meal for user who does not exist yet*/
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Inserts new user to database
func insertUser(with uid: String,completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
    database.child("users").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
        if var usersCollection = snapshot.value as? [String]{
            // while user is more than 0
            //append user id
            usersCollection.append(uid)
            database.child("users").setValue(usersCollection,withCompletionBlock: {error, _ in
                guard error == nil else{
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
                completion(true)
            })
        }
        else{
            // while first user of app
            // create that array
            let newCollection: [String] = [uid]
            database.child("users").setValue(newCollection,withCompletionBlock: {error, _ in
                guard error == nil else{
                    completion(false)
                    return
                }
                completion(true)
            })
        }
    })
}
```

check user exist for those user who deleted app earlier

```
/// check for user exist
func userExists(with uid:String,
                       completion: @escaping ((Bool) -> Void)){
    database.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in
        guard snapshot.value as? [String : Any] != nil else{ // date type as per your input
            print("user doesnt exist")
            completion(false)
            return
        }
        print(snapshot.value!)
        print("user exists")
        completion(true)
    })
}
```

Comment: After adding this code to the View Controller, do I just call insertUser in the else statement?

Comment: @akshaysub27 yes you can. add user exist if needed